# Get page content from page built with Thrive Content Builder WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create an XML file that displays page content, so I can use these pages on another website.

If i try it with a normal page I can get the page title and content:

```
$thepost = get_post($postID);
$title = $thepost->post_title;
$content = $thepost->post_content;
```

But I want to get the content of a page that is built with Thrive Content Builder, and these pages are not stored in post_content.

So is there any way to get this page content?